# Как реализовать взаимодействие с таблицей нормализации?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Привет. Есть такая диаграмма - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Техника у сотрудников может быть общая, поэтому создал таблицу нормализации. Если я хочу добавить новую запись(через WPF) техники, то нужно будет вводить данные о техники и id сотрудника которому она принадлежит. Можно ли в запросе сделать так, чтобы все связи в nomTech автоматически вводились? Допустим ввожу данные о технике и ID сотрудника = 5 в таблицу нормализации автоматически заносится id техники и id сотрудника. Такое возможно реализовать? И как потом делать выборку по техники в зависимости от id сотрудника?

Comment: Вы ORM какую-нибудь используете или работаете через ADO.Net ?

Comment: ado.net + entety, но писать нужно на sql все запросы

Comment: Если все запросы вы пишите на sql, то все решается правильным написанием этих самых запросов. Вы хотите чтоб вам помогли с sql?

Comment: @Bulson да. Нужна помощь...